# Debugging an iPhone crash report

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, crash-reports

How do I debug the following crash report?

A user installs the App from the App Store but the App crashes when loaded. I cannot re-produce the crash myself. I went to my crash reports on my own iPad and found a similar one, but again, cannot re-produce it. The problem is for the user that it prevents the App from loading (whereas, the crash I found myself just crashed the App, but it works fine when restarted).

Is there anybody who can point me in the way to debug the below?

```
SysInfoCrashReporterKey
31136b81228e5ddf6387c3aed3543d3580bcca2c
bug_type
109
description
Incident Identifier: F112DB19-91AA-4184-8B66-D2D80E451652
CrashReported Key: 31136b81228e5ddf6387c3aed3543d3580bcca2c
Hardware Model: iPad2,2
Process: iDomsReader [776]
Path: /var/mobile/Applications/0A50B09F-C579-425A-8EB8-95F4C5517929/iDomsReader.app/iDomsReader
Identifier: iDomsReader
Version: ??? (???)
Code Type: ARM (Native)
Parent Process: launchd [1]

Date/Time: 2012-02-04 12:55:59.542 -0700
OS Version: iPhone OS 5.0.1 (9A405)
Report Version: 104

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa001af11
Crashed Thread: 10

Thread 0 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e49010 0x36e48000 + 4112
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e49206 0x36e48000 + 4614
2 CoreFoundation 0x343b641c 0x34329000 + 578588
3 CoreFoundation 0x343b511a 0x34329000 + 573722
4 CoreFoundation 0x343384d6 0x34329000 + 62678
5 CoreFoundation 0x3433839e 0x34329000 + 62366
6 GraphicsServices 0x30c23fc6 0x30c20000 + 16326
7 UIKit 0x3290073c 0x328cf000 + 202556
8 iDomsReader 0x00002608 0x1000 + 5640
9 iDomsReader 0x000025c0 0x1000 + 5568

Thread 1 name: Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e493b4 0x36e48000 + 5044
1 libdispatch.dylib 0x333dff74 0x333dc000 + 16244
2 libdispatch.dylib 0x333dfc92 0x333dc000 + 15506

Thread 2 name: WebThread
Thread 2:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e49010 0x36e48000 + 4112
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e49206 0x36e48000 + 4614
2 CoreFoundation 0x343b641c 0x34329000 + 578588
3 CoreFoundation 0x343b5154 0x34329000 + 573780
4 CoreFoundation 0x343384d6 0x34329000 + 62678
5 CoreFoundation 0x3433839e 0x34329000 + 62366
6 WebCore 0x33869128 0x337c1000 + 688424
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84c16 0x32f75000 + 64534
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84ad0 0x32f75000 + 64208

Thread 3 name: com.apple.coremedia.player.async
Thread 3:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e59068 0x36e48000 + 69736
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84f2e 0x32f75000 + 65326
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84caa 0x32f75000 + 64682
3 CoreMedia 0x3736d000 0x3736a000 + 12288
4 MediaToolbox 0x314b2fba 0x314af000 + 16314
5 CoreMedia 0x3738cbc6 0x3736a000 + 142278
6 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84c16 0x32f75000 + 64534
7 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84ad0 0x32f75000 + 64208

Thread 4 name: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 4:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e49010 0x36e48000 + 4112
1 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e49206 0x36e48000 + 4614
2 CoreFoundation 0x343b641c 0x34329000 + 578588
3 CoreFoundation 0x343b5154 0x34329000 + 573780
4 CoreFoundation 0x343384d6 0x34329000 + 62678
5 CoreFoundation 0x3433839e 0x34329000 + 62366
6 Foundation 0x32db3bc2 0x32da3000 + 68546
7 Foundation 0x32db3a8a 0x32da3000 + 68234
8 Foundation 0x32e4759a 0x32da3000 + 673178
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84c16 0x32f75000 + 64534
10 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84ad0 0x32f75000 + 64208

Thread 5 name: com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 5:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e59570 0x36e48000 + 71024
1 CoreFoundation 0x343ba66a 0x34329000 + 595562
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84c16 0x32f75000 + 64534
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84ad0 0x32f75000 + 64208

Thread 6:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e59cd4 0x36e48000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f30a 0x32f75000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f09c 0x32f75000 + 41116

Thread 7:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e59cd4 0x36e48000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f30a 0x32f75000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f09c 0x32f75000 + 41116

Thread 8:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e59cd4 0x36e48000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f30a 0x32f75000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f09c 0x32f75000 + 41116

Thread 9:
0 libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x36e59cd4 0x36e48000 + 72916
1 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f30a 0x32f75000 + 41738
2 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f7f09c 0x32f75000 + 41116

Thread 10 Crashed:
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x357f7fbc 0x357f4000 + 16316
1 Foundation 0x32e47e1e 0x32da3000 + 675358
2 CoreFoundation 0x343b2a28 0x34329000 + 563752
3 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f766c8 0x32f75000 + 5832
4 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f76344 0x32f75000 + 4932
5 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f885c4 0x32f75000 + 79300
6 Foundation 0x32dc3384 0x32da3000 + 131972
7 Foundation 0x32e475b8 0x32da3000 + 673208
8 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84c16 0x32f75000 + 64534
9 libsystem_c.dylib 0x32f84ad0 0x32f75000 + 64208

Thread 10 crashed with ARM Thread State:
r0: 0x00158170 r1: 0x371c809c r2: 0x001ad5a0 r3: 0x00000000
r4: 0xa001af09 r5: 0x3efb99c4 r6: 0x3efb99f4 r7: 0x03ee3d80
r8: 0x3efa4374 r9: 0x0dc72027 r10: 0x00000000 r11: 0x00000037
ip: 0x3ef7f6f0 sp: 0x03ee3bf0 lr: 0x32e47e25 pc: 0x357f7fbc
cpsr: 0x00000030

Binary Images:
0x1000 - 0x9dfff +iDomsReader armv7 <ea01ecefcd773fe28d8ef84125373c1e> /var/mobile/Applications/0A50B09F-C579-425A-8EB8-95F4C5517929/iDomsReader.app/iDomsReader
0x2fe9e000 - 0x2febffff dyld armv7 <be7c0b491a943054ad12eb5060f1da06> /usr/lib/dyld
0x30639000 - 0x30645fff libCRFSuite.dylib armv7 <ea460e3f1ac338a9885d5752864dbffb> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x30646000 - 0x30686fff libGLImage.dylib armv7 <9440420d838a382caa175399d74a5044> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGLImage.dylib
0x30687000 - 0x30706fff libsqlite3.dylib armv7 <af4718fee01734748c42f2214ab6883d> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x3073d000 - 0x308f9fff ImageIO armv7 <df300f66a317352e92354a8a48af3453> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x30a54000 - 0x30a54fff vecLib armv7 <106ef8294b0d3c2d89e9230527846227> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/vecLib
0x30a61000 - 0x30a68fff ProtocolBuffer armv7 <6ca7dca9370132a2a592356bf9f2170b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x30a6d000 - 0x30a7cfff SpringBoardServices armv7 <79f1564c1b23303eb3b7db67f9375228> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework/SpringBoardServices
0x30a83000 - 0x30be0fff libmecabra.dylib armv7 <170c82a3c716372abe7ae0aae96d4805> /usr/lib/libmecabra.dylib
0x30c0b000 - 0x30c1cfff DataAccessExpress armv7 <6bc443b0f87e338698cac9e5a96e8f8f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataAccessExpress.framework/DataAccessExpress
0x30c1d000 - 0x30c1ffff MobileInstallation armv7 <4ccf76f0e6cb3cd7b4e0087c2f284a1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileInstallation.framework/MobileInstallation
0x30c20000 - 0x30c2bfff GraphicsServices armv7 <4ec745ffb2e039faab4b39a30268f707> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x30d39000 - 0x30d3ffff liblaunch.dylib armv7 <09f21c3e774c30b1aab1b56c2d6efbc3> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib
0x30d7f000 - 0x30d7ffff libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib armv7 <85582e1094633fccb52b50ca13c5a5d0> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCVMSPluginSupport.dylib
0x30ed9000 - 0x30f83fff libBLAS.dylib armv7 <9aabff01422f3cb8960f93d11d2b6de1> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libBLAS.dylib
0x30fbe000 - 0x30fc4fff IAP armv7 <f6a99995c7de3db8a52e9a35aac063bc> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IAP.framework/IAP
0x31007000 - 0x3104afff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7 <be9a231cfe6e3ae387abb444a098bce9> /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
0x3104b000 - 0x3106efff Bom armv7 <0e6087f75a81345ea81751197ccb712c> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Bom.framework/Bom
0x310e9000 - 0x31123fff iTunesStore armv7 <abf9395fcf8b3c13b9638b85541484c7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/iTunesStore.framework/iTunesStore
0x311fb000 - 0x31202fff libc++abi.dylib armv7 <f769ce305c3033ee90e8c2ecc4846619> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x31229000 - 0x3123afff AirTraffic armv7 <187da49948ed3897aeac049cab658528> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AirTraffic.framework/AirTraffic
0x3123b000 - 0x3123cfff DataMigration armv7 <d067b65a904a3f438b5d9e13b208b117> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DataMigration.framework/DataMigration
0x3123d000 - 0x31317fff vImage armv7 <42a5e58ff1b9350cad90de36bd3ceb09> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vImage.framework/vImage
0x31458000 - 0x31475fff libsystem_info.dylib armv7 <1e36ab94661c372bab5a801d68c79353> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x314af000 - 0x31709fff MediaToolbox armv7 <ab91ec33f2b23606bd0443163beff710> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaToolbox.framework/MediaToolbox
0x3171c000 - 0x31722fff libnotify.dylib armv7 <1e374857ac68370095ddbafe94f021a1> /usr/lib/system/libnotify.dylib
0x317ef000 - 0x317effff libkeymgr.dylib armv7 <791bb8b832943b2392c0c35228f52e09> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib
0x317f7000 - 0x31806fff OpenGLES armv7 <6d1afb451f50310895ec59864739e781> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/OpenGLES
0x3197a000 - 0x3198bfff libxpc.dylib armv7 <7d49e385ee5d3e7eb08d06525abd6435> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x3198c000 - 0x31a38fff MediaControlSender armv7 <4c0982b21ecf35aead8e0bef55d842b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaControlSender.framework/MediaControlSender
0x31a39000 - 0x31a3cfff libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7 <414332f9a55238bab2cbec323e0fc8da> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
0x31a3d000 - 0x31a88fff CoreLocation armv7 <e959d4dd596b31eeaa49c8c0156b1e12> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x31abc000 - 0x31c6dfff MediaPlayer armv7 <ef8f1f4574823f41899569ea48367903> /System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/MediaPlayer
0x31c83000 - 0x31c8afff AssetsLibraryServices armv7 <c0093954f6ee329aa6b4848215bcb8c0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices
0x31dc0000 - 0x31de0fff libxslt.1.dylib armv7 <f37418b7e89137bba433677d61cd779d> /usr/lib/libxslt.1.dylib
0x3201f000 - 0x3202afff AccountSettings armv7 <090bb6a4f97433089b5cabc6a40c619a> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AccountSettings.framework/AccountSettings
0x327bd000 - 0x3288efff HomeSharing armv7 <c336db6393593be0ae24d18d34363b35> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HomeSharing.framework/HomeSharing
0x328cf000 - 0x32d68fff UIKit armv7 <97b527cd6fba35c6bb39263e0f362223> /System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit
0x32da3000 - 0x32f21fff Foundation armv7 <ce466f428d953caaac6641d186665809> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x32f5f000 - 0x32f74fff libresolv.9.dylib armv7 <97d6ebbb53ae3e0480f51771c9665613> /usr/lib/libresolv.9.dylib
0x32f75000 - 0x33002fff libsystem_c.dylib armv7 <1707c3cf3c5b3045af4bed38ff8420a6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x3300c000 - 0x33055fff ManagedConfiguration armv7 <05711081dd883c58a844c5f9c251e8c9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x33392000 - 0x333dbfff AddressBook armv7 <0a858565acd03f28a1bc69a650b64a7b> /System/Library/Frameworks/AddressBook.framework/AddressBook
0x333dc000 - 0x333f2fff libdispatch.dylib armv7 <defe319d1f4d3c1c8c4f18ebd96b396a> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x3343e000 - 0x33441fff CaptiveNetwork armv7 <c3a5b1659eb0302eb205498ffacb09f1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CaptiveNetwork.framework/CaptiveNetwork
0x33442000 - 0x33444fff libCoreVMClient.dylib armv7 <6ddb7cf8a93830628787a5b83eea0f1d> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libCoreVMClient.dylib
0x33519000 - 0x33521fff MobileWiFi armv7 <f07cb8d6dadf36919bae8ef6e5ce1749> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileWiFi.framework/MobileWiFi
0x33522000 - 0x33547fff OpenCL armv7 <e1d5bfcdb59934b0923b9307c75e7457> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/OpenCL.framework/OpenCL
0x335eb000 - 0x3360efff PrintKit armv7 <279fb51deec3377ab9f820af2da4d915> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintKit.framework/PrintKit
0x337c1000 - 0x33f78fff WebCore armv7 <7137e0ea008f3a3e8ae9e57f96d34d1d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebCore.framework/WebCore
0x34085000 - 0x34088fff libsystem_network.dylib armv7 <b18e0a845b1e317c8abcf6b5d06b29a0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib
0x34089000 - 0x3408dfff IOSurface armv7 <0f003f50b18e3dbf87607d819e0ac6b9> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOSurface.framework/IOSurface
0x3408e000 - 0x3413bfff libxml2.2.dylib armv7 <78462273eb5b38d1a0873b02f0e35e23> /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib
0x34145000 - 0x34235fff QuartzCore armv7 <ff595b1a042933249466e92433e1af6f> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x34236000 - 0x34237fff CoreSurface armv7 <fcb6a869daef3a3abc4300c28b218e9f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreSurface.framework/CoreSurface
0x34306000 - 0x34310fff libbz2.1.0.dylib armv7 <28583efb9f1b38e7ae83c667b07dbd08> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib
0x34329000 - 0x34440fff CoreFoundation armv7 <de9eefc6109735369cfd8f3de9895da0> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x34441000 - 0x3444bfff libvMisc.dylib armv7 <b93ee3136d1c3d44b1e513a56bb0f86c> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvMisc.dylib
0x34450000 - 0x34464fff PersistentConnection armv7 <81eb1b3e08cf3d7196313307ad60649d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PersistentConnection.framework/PersistentConnection
0x34465000 - 0x3447bfff DictionaryServices armv7 <5bbab664f97932a79a1566fda3a4383e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DictionaryServices.framework/DictionaryServices
0x349a4000 - 0x349a5fff libremovefile.dylib armv7 <9c8cee9652453241ac1fc99eab05c40a> /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib
0x349ef000 - 0x349f4fff CrashReporterSupport armv7 <c3062554536438f9874c88363df7f60b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CrashReporterSupport.framework/CrashReporterSupport
0x34a0b000 - 0x34ac6fff AVFoundation armv7 <c971a925b82934f8881283aabb2992f5> /System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation
0x34ac7000 - 0x34ad4fff libbsm.0.dylib armv7 <a6414b0a5fd53df58c4f0b2f8878f81f> /usr/lib/libbsm.0.dylib
0x34ae6000 - 0x34aeafff libcache.dylib armv7 <4511f0ec5b713636aaade7245a12553c> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
0x34aeb000 - 0x34af1fff MobileKeyBag armv7 <f5633749a1c83058a28cd7d0b488e19f> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x34af9000 - 0x34dbafff libLAPACK.dylib armv7 <5490a87fe5153771b9c67940292842ba> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libLAPACK.dylib
0x34dbb000 - 0x34dbffff libAccessibility.dylib armv7 <ee734c0e964934a887a66d170270b114> /usr/lib/libAccessibility.dylib
0x34dc2000 - 0x34dd1fff GenerationalStorage armv7 <c581bffc87013530b3c2d017142395e6> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GenerationalStorage.framework/GenerationalStorage
0x34f3d000 - 0x34f43fff MobileIcons armv7 <2f4c13053206306996726629b0b7eb01> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileIcons.framework/MobileIcons
0x34f58000 - 0x34f94fff AppSupport armv7 <de0c2fbb95f8383db43acfb44e9c66fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x34f9f000 - 0x34fa3fff libGFXShared.dylib armv7 <0a36fb9d60a43479943bafb2f81313b1> /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGLES.framework/libGFXShared.dylib
0x34fba000 - 0x354fefff FaceCoreLight armv7 <cc2edb3645d2390dbca5471d35f1bf6e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FaceCoreLight.framework/FaceCoreLight
0x3550a000 - 0x3550bfff libdyld.dylib armv7 <f1963e7ef64e39a58ec1e39ed7c74849> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x35510000 - 0x35510fff Accelerate armv7 <a62771c826753815a5cae96eaa60ffd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Accelerate
0x35535000 - 0x3557ffff libvDSP.dylib armv7 <d8489a4ce77933abac52394c43ff5513> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libvDSP.dylib
0x35580000 - 0x35581fff libsystem_blocks.dylib armv7 <4bb9797771d037879bec814fe750d86d> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x355cb000 - 0x3561cfff libstdc++.6.dylib armv7 <dc2061145c1a3307829d4f3bfc547c1a> /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
0x35666000 - 0x35736fff WebKit armv7 <74661b1bf4613aafb827bfe0134ed92b> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WebKit.framework/WebKit
0x35739000 - 0x35774fff libCGFreetype.A.dylib armv7 <753daf497ca736739a30126661a522f1> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libCGFreetype.A.dylib
0x35779000 - 0x35782fff libMobileGestalt.dylib armv7 <bf8d7c30f11a393a8adf4c8277e65aa3> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x35783000 - 0x357f3fff CoreImage armv7 <b1d0678497f43769840f173c0f9dce20> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x357f4000 - 0x358bafff libobjc.A.dylib armv7 <ebbb32df194b331e9b3dc14e40f46833> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x358bb000 - 0x358c1fff liblockdown.dylib armv7 <bfaf7fb16e5a3b2ea07c47b8b2f2b64e> /usr/lib/liblockdown.dylib
0x35934000 - 0x3597dfff libc++.1.dylib armv7 <ad15503487243836b7c296f3439ba0c1> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x35d41000 - 0x35dbafff ProofReader armv7 <09d057676f6837cd9e7a735444b67e77> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProofReader.framework/ProofReader
0x35f3b000 - 0x3601afff RawCamera armv7 <4fb932b6a2d83c4eadfcecf53220699a> /System/Library/CoreServices/RawCamera.bundle/RawCamera
0x36034000 - 0x36034fff libunwind.dylib armv7 <d21222aad8c93d6c9580f9bf47071946> /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib
0x36085000 - 0x360bcfff Security armv7 <b89c9f6373f037f2a4801558f97b9a95> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x360bd000 - 0x360f6fff VideoToolbox armv7 <49f9f09f23f7396b94a29bb1280759fe> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/VideoToolbox.framework/VideoToolbox
0x360f7000 - 0x3623cfff CoreGraphics armv7 <641fb6e558f239588a8bd05dbefff99a> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics
0x3623d000 - 0x363d5fff CoreData armv7 <dd6d139d99e5309f9df33f7b6a044b16> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x36411000 - 0x36416fff libsystem_dnssd.dylib armv7 <4d8b38f1cb603f0d8af78c56c485f05a> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib
0x36449000 - 0x364ccfff CoreMotion armv7 <f4365ff3974b3049b3f04b3f55a46ae6> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMotion.framework/CoreMotion
0x365a0000 - 0x365d5fff SystemConfiguration armv7 <753be0ebdcb13b24b1a4adcdc94d6bd9> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x3667d000 - 0x3667efff libdnsinfo.dylib armv7 <dbd1e77a4beb309d8f160d927d442467> /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib
0x366a6000 - 0x366c5fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7 <31a0ffbb18bf3a28b46fd286733e7d9f> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
0x366c6000 - 0x367b4fff libiconv.2.dylib armv7 <6e858938edb93162ba8cf25702f08b16> /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
0x367b5000 - 0x367cbfff libmis.dylib armv7 <fd046316dedc34dd81a6601ea3b1e8a6> /usr/lib/libmis.dylib
0x367cc000 - 0x367d3fff MediaRemote armv7 <3deff2252a8231e7b0135a517b8391ba> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MediaRemote.framework/MediaRemote
0x367d4000 - 0x367e0fff libz.1.dylib armv7 <eef915ed9b2c3433b03fd9030957b945> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib
0x36845000 - 0x36848fff libmacho.dylib armv7 <3237bc9c109e3354bc4b38b957243f31> /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib
0x3684c000 - 0x36865fff libRIP.A.dylib armv7 <ad22ea5ee99a358691f9820e62c85058> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Resources/libRIP.A.dylib
0x3686a000 - 0x3686efff AggregateDictionary armv7 <cfd957904957310381369729bfd9b2b0> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x369ad000 - 0x36a08fff StoreServices armv7 <1463a9f90fbd3d349544cf016e1ddd46> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/StoreServices.framework/StoreServices
0x36a09000 - 0x36a4efff GeoServices armv7 <6c9eb6372f723a57852cfc9ed7b78e31> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GeoServices.framework/GeoServices
0x36b38000 - 0x36b3bfff CoreTime armv7 <e2f02260f2a63359b9a0a47c69f59c9e> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreTime.framework/CoreTime
0x36b3e000 - 0x36b8ffff CoreText armv7 <23150093d39b393e9bc5f8230176df47> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x36e02000 - 0x36e46fff MobileCoreServices armv7 <9a79a2d389ba35389a30782ed01c46dd> /System/Library/Frameworks/MobileCoreServices.framework/MobileCoreServices
0x36e48000 - 0x36e5efff libsystem_kernel.dylib armv7 <afd3cb06e20336dca2e5a6e11d080504> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x36e88000 - 0x36e89fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib armv7 <b8612b4ce18535aaa94f4b75c730e090> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib
0x36eb8000 - 0x37229fff TextInput armv7 <64d1227219b03c51ba4854ec2f79c335> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/TextInput.framework/TextInput
0x3736a000 - 0x373b3fff CoreMedia armv7 <d585cf4e0cfa34fa8beaa43b06a4bcd7> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMedia.framework/CoreMedia
0x3754a000 - 0x37706fff MusicLibrary armv7 <7be04d376ebc3d419ad408284cef681d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MusicLibrary.framework/MusicLibrary
0x37719000 - 0x378f6fff AudioToolbox armv7 <da4f78fd20fb3b42b1a8be4f383d9c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox
0x37905000 - 0x3791bfff EAP8021X armv7 <16801802d86e3c479f3034034192faed> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/EAP8021X.framework/EAP8021X
0x37926000 - 0x37932fff CoreVideo armv7 <474c89eb09fe3464851a20d76052341b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreVideo.framework/CoreVideo
0x37933000 - 0x37933fff libgcc_s.1.dylib armv7 <69d8dab7388b33d38b30708fd6b6a340> /usr/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib
0x37a62000 - 0x37b39fff CFNetwork armv7 <6fbc9f187eaa30009780e70288c9f289> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x37b5f000 - 0x37ca8fff libicucore.A.dylib armv7 <1bc960f75d633190a09b093209a9f0c5> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x37db9000 - 0x37e03fff CoreTelephony armv7 <1f4cacb552533c948122cb180f4192b3> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x37e04000 - 0x37e41fff IOKit armv7 <e5f727892ee034a4be04e6da608f413f> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x37eba000 - 0x37fdefff JavaScriptCore armv7 <24ff2747b3973aecb9c37960eba5ff4d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x3814b000 - 0x38214fff Celestial armv7 <c18e76311fc33016be930da83050b96d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Celestial.framework/Celestial
0x38221000 - 0x38226fff libcopyfile.dylib armv7 <9072462f28af3665875b3ecaba002c00> /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
0x38227000 - 0x3822bfff IOMobileFramebuffer armv7 <c2e6bd6dafde3097b47bc255a8c871ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/IOMobileFramebuffer.framework/IOMobileFramebuffer
0x382ae000 - 0x38305fff CoreAudio armv7 <2e4975a2156e328585f2a478e80704fc> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x38367000 - 0x38367fff liblangid.dylib armv7 <342170169bf232a0888912f5ef97112d> /usr/lib/liblangid.dylib
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this crash report in your Xcode organizer? If not put it in there, and see if it symbolicates it, will give you more information about where the crash occurred.

Comment: I found the same (or very similar) crash on my own iPad. But it just shows as plain text in the organizer. I am not able to reproduce the error on my own iPad however, so cannot use the debugger.

Comment: Sounds like you haven't saved the dysm file, I'm assuming you used Application Loader rather the build->Archive in Xcode to submit your app. In this case there isn't a lot that can be done. Id recommend using Build-Archive from now on, just because it automatically saves your .dysm files needed for symbolicating your crash logs

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you do two things:

- To integrate a crash reporting library such as [Instabug](http://instabug.com) will help you get more details about the type of device, software version, CPU load, memory usage, and connectivity. All of which are important factors when it comes to debugging and reproducing the crash.
- Your crash reports are not symbolicated. You first have to locate your project’s dSYM file. Below is the fastest way to locate your project's dSYM

  ```
  mdfind "com_apple_xcode_dsym_uuids == your-UUID-here"
  ```

  Your UUID can be found on top of Instabug's dashboard.
  You can then upload your dSYM file through the dashboard so you can get more comprehensible crash reports.

---

For full disclosure, I work at Instabug. Let me know if I can help.

Answer (score 6):

The crashing thread 10 has only Apple framework calls, nothing from your app. Those will symbolicate if the symbolication script has the iOS 5.0.1 symbols accessible via Spotlight. Your apps dSYM won't help for that stack trace.

Since the exception type is [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) you won't find a line number in the crashing thread which causes the crash. You have somewhere (could be anywhere!) in your code a memory problem, which causes the app trying to access a memory address which is actually invalid. Hence, causing the crash.

Symbolication of Thread 10 gives in the following result:

```
Thread 10 Crashed:
0 libobjc.A.dylib                   0x31516fbc objc_msgSend + 16
1 Foundation                        0x31970e1e __NSFinalizeThreadData + 1078
2 CoreFoundation                    0x37a06a28 __CFTSDFinalize + 60
3 libsystem_c.dylib                 0x35e506c8 _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 164
4 libsystem_c.dylib                 0x35e50344 _pthread_exit + 116
5 libsystem_c.dylib                 0x35e625c4 pthread_exit + 24
6 Foundation                        0x318ec384 +[NSThread exit] + 4
7 Foundation                        0x319705b8 __NSThread__main__ + 1072
8 libsystem_c.dylib                 0x35e5ec16 _pthread_start + 314
9 libsystem_c.dylib                 0x35e5ead0 thread_start + 0
```

obj_msgSend is another hint to the memory issue, and it looks like this happened after you started some code in a new thread. So you might want to check those places in your threading code. Maybe you are accessing an ivar that is already released in another thread.

In general the best way I found to reliable find and resolve memory issues was using a testing framework and automate the app interaction so it runs a long time. It also helps to automate it by redoing the same user interaction over and over again. It will most likely crash, but this time reproducible so you can run the automation with instruments aside. I did use the [KIF](https://github.com/square/KIF/) framework with great success for that.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to `symbolicate` your crash reports.

These couple of links may help you somewhat.

http://kevincupp.com/2011/05/12/symbolicating-ios-crash-logs.html

http://www.buildingiphoneapps.com/2011/03/processing-users-crash-logs-when.html

If you have not saved the `.dSYM` for that build, of are not able to symbolicate the crash, then you should start doing so from next release onwards, so that you may understand the crash reports next time.

Comment: Thanks Sailesh, that is a very good tip! However, for me it didn't shed any light on the issue, still the same on Thread 10

Comment: As I said, if you do not have the corresponding dSYM, then this crash report can not give you any info. There is nothing you can do, except learn from this mistake and saving the dSYM from next time onwards. If you have something to upgrade your app, save the dSYM for that build, and use it symbolicate crashes for that build.

Comment: Well, maybe I am just out of luck then. I used the dSYM out of the archive, and it does show on the main thread "iDomsReader                    0x00002608 main (main.m:14)" suggesting something works, but not on Thread 10 which crashes.

Answer (score 0):

it's maybe happened when you release more time or use object after release it.

check your source code.

Comment: Well, it us rather a large chunk of code, and as I cannot reproduce the error on my own iPad I don't know where to start looking

Comment: @LuukD.Jansen maybe you can reproduce when you receive a memory warning