# Cannot figure out why app crashed in review on iTunes

Tags: ios, crash, app-store-connect, crash-reports

Our app was tested on a number of devices over testflight etc but when we submitted our app to the app store the reviewer reported that the app crashed and rejected it. We have not been able to reproduce the crash. The following crash report was gathered but it's not as helpful as I would have hoped.

Can anyone help me decipher this crash log? I would really appreciate it

Thanks

```
{"app_name":"My App","app_version":"139","bundleID":"my.app","adam_id":889978956,"os_version":"iPhone OS 8.0 (12A365)","slice_uuid":"36c1d096-db60-3100-9039-a713f038516f","share_with_app_devs":false,"build_version":"2.0","is_first_party":false,"bug_type":"109","name":"My App"}
Incident Identifier: AC8B2024-88A0-4A38-804A-980FAEF463EE
CrashReporter Key:   e507fa34ffcb22f0c5c51a0e7631d57931794afb
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             My App [855]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/C3C22C54-9565-456F-9714-C6FF89A04ABE/My App.app/My App
Identifier:          my.app
Version:             2.0 (139)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-27 09:04:06.780 -0700
Launch Time:         2014-09-27 09:04:03.097 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 8.0 (12A365)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x243ece3f 0x31ea0c8b 0x243ecd85 0x27c45509 0x27b66233 0x279a61ed 0x2788a3d9 0x2788a35d 0x1c7313 0x17531d 0x2788a5ef 0x2788a35d 0x1c15db 0x2788a5ef 0x2788a35d 0x27a137b9 0x27933407 0x2793320d 0x279331a1 0x27887b37 0x272afccd 0x272ab6b5 0x272ab53d 0x272aaf21 0x272aad25 0x272a4bfd 0x243b35cd 0x243b0c8b 0x243b1093 0x242ff621 0x242ff433 0x2b6530a9 0x278e9809 0x1099df 0x32420aaf)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib        0x324e6dfc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x32564d33 pthread_kill + 59
2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x32486905 abort + 73
3   libc++abi.dylib               0x317c29c5 abort_message + 85
4   libc++abi.dylib               0x317dc66d default_terminate_handler() + 265
5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x31ea0f23 _objc_terminate() + 191
6   libc++abi.dylib               0x317d9de1 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 77
7   libc++abi.dylib               0x317d98ab __cxa_rethrow + 99
8   libobjc.A.dylib               0x31ea0dcf objc_exception_rethrow + 39
9   CoreFoundation                0x242ff6b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 629
10  CoreFoundation                0x242ff42f CFRunLoopRunInMode + 103
11  GraphicsServices              0x2b6530a5 GSEventRunModal + 133
12  UIKit                         0x278e9805 UIApplicationMain + 1437
13  My App                    0x001099db main + 67
14  libdyld.dylib                 0x32420aad start + 1
```

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log.

Comment: Did you put this crash report in your Xcode organizer? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9148516/debugging-an-iphone-crash-report

Comment: Unfortunately, our builds are done using scripts so that and the machine that build this had a hard drive failure. I don't have the dSYm file :(